# adjacency matrix of weighted directed graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, shortest-path

A) Suppose `A` be a adjacency matrix of weighted directed graph `G` with `n` vertex in which `A[i,j]` be a weight of edge `i` to `j`. if there is no such edge `A[i ,i]=0`. Matrix `A^K= A*A*A*...A`.  if we use + instead of * and use `min` instead of +, Slot `A^k [i,j]` not describe weight of path `i` to `j` with at most `k` edge. I want to find this problem show  what things?

B) Suppose `A` be a adjacency matrix of weighted directed graph (wihout loop and multiple edge) `G` with `n` vertex in which `A[i,j]` be a weight of edge `i` to `j`. if there is no such edge `A[i ,j]=infinity`, and for evrey `i` we have `A[i, i]=0`. Matrix `A^K= A*A*A*...A`.  Slot `A^k [i,j]` Show what things? min weight? or...?

any idea?

Edit: i means these algorithm find which in graph? find maximum weight? min weight? find nothing?

Comment: *I want to find this problem show what things?* -- What?

Comment: Dear @aioobe, this algorithm find which in graph? find maximum weight? min weight? find nothing?

Comment: So.. I assume you mean "generalized matrix multiplication with two operators, now `minimum` and `addition` instead of `addition` and `multiplication` respectively", but it's actually not super clear from your question

Comment: Dear @harold, yes you are right.

Comment: It would look a lot like Floyd–Warshall.

Comment: i confusing so much when see these problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Let `B = A^K`

`B[i, j]` would represent shortest path from `i .. j` that takes exactly `k` steps. How ?

Given a Matrix `A` what happens if we multiple `A` with itself ?

```
    // Initialize a matrix result which would be the matrix obtained by A*A
    vector< N, vector<int> (N, INF) > result;
    REP(i,0,N) REP(j,0,N) REP(k,0,N)
        result[i][j] = min(result[i][j], (A[i][k] + A[k][j]));
```

Initially `A[i, j]` had the direct cost of going to `j` from `i`. As you can see that `result[i, j]` is `minimum` of `result[i, j]` and `A[i, k] + A[k, j]`, So we conclude that `result[i, j]` contains path going from `i .. j` using one intermediate vertex `k`. And since we iterate this for all `k's`, `result[i, j]` contains the minimum cost path that traverses exactly two edges. We can now generalize for `A^k`.

What if we set `A[i, i]` to `0` ?

This allows self loops. In the above code when `k == i`,

```
    result[i, j] = min(result[i,j], A[i, i] + A[i, j])
    result[i, j] = min(result[i,j], A[i,j)] // since A[i, i] = 0;
```

This means that now `result[i, j]` would denote the shortest path to reach from `i .. j` if we can use either one or two edges.

So Now `B[i, j]` would represent shortest path from `i .. j` that takes almost `k` steps.

Similarly, We can use the same concept to calculate no of paths from `i .. j` that take exactly `k` steps. What you can do is that initialize `A[i, j]` as `1` if we have an edge between `i` and `j` else `0`.

`A^k` would give you the desired result.

Comment: Dear Ninja429, would you please descirbe (a) and (b) caclualte what thing? i read your wrote but in a summerize and short words describe for me? thanks a lots. i approve and vote up. for example (a) find ... and algorithm (b) find ... . thanks.

Comment: A finds the minimum path to go from any vertex i .. j using exactly k edges, B finds the minimum path to go from any vertex i .. j using atmost k paths.

Comment: Dear @Ninja, would you please distinct your answer for clarity in part (a) and (b).

Comment: Dear @Ninja, i wait for accept it. please distinct your part of solution for (a) and (b).

Comment: as I said above, 
a) finds the minimum path to go from any vertex i .. j using exactly k edges, b) finds the minimum path to go from any vertex i .. j using atmost k paths

Comment: i know it. please edit your answer for part (a) and (b).